# Disabling all React related lint warnings on ESLint

Tags: eslint, standardjs

I am working on a project which uses JSX without React. ESLint thinks I am using React because of JSX, how can I disable all React related linter warnings?

For example, I am having these warnings:

```
Standard: error
Missing "key" prop for element in iterator (react/jsx-key)

Standard: error
Empty components are self-closing (react/self-closing-comp)
```

Is there a way I can disable all the warnings that start with `react`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into eslint documentaion [ESLint official docs](https://eslint.org/docs/2.13.1/user-guide/configuring#disabling-rules-with-inline-comments), the only way you can disable `react/***` rules is by creating `.eslintrc` file and disabling the rules explicitly.

Another work around for it would be to remove the npm package of `eslint-plugin-react` which will remove the React ESLint rules totally and you won't have to explicitly disable the rules in `.eslintrc` file.